# Call an event on play video for the first time using angular

Tags: html, events, video, angular7

I am using simple HTML5 video controller and i am trying to achieve the things where if user click on play button for the first time then i need to track it.

I tried below

```
<video controls (click)="toggleVideo()" #videoPlayer>
  <source src="test.mp4" type="mp4" />
  Browser not supported
</video>
```

and from ts file inside toggleVideo() method i am able to play video but not able to detect that when user plays this video for the first time.

Comment: Is this solved or do you still need an answer? I can show you with regular JS (I don't involve Angular).

Comment: @VC.One, Do you see any answers? using regular js everyone can achieve this. i am using angular.

Comment: **(1)** Not seeing answer does not mean anything. You might have got solution already but just not shared the solution here, for all I know.  **(2)** `using regular js everyone can achieve this. i am using angular` so just use a JS function for this? Typescript is a variation of Javascript (they are compatible within same code). **(3)** Whether TS or JS, you need a integer variable (set to zero) to keep track of amount-of-clicks, then function `toggleVideo()` can add `+1` per click with `myInt +=1;` followed by an IF statement eg: `if ( myInt == 1) { alert( "video has first time click" ); }`